# Flow control using if statements

Tags: php

I have `300+` rows of data that i am getting from various users of our cloud application. Users are using the web application on mobile and on computers.Since we are using responsive designs,it interests us we know what the users are using to access the application.

We are interested in the common known manufacturers like so

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qs', 'qs_root', 'lepasswort');
$fc = $dbh->prepare("select str from test_str");
$fc->execute();

$i = 0;
while($result = $fc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$one = $result['str'];

$cmd = "/usr/bin/perl str_processor.pl  '$one' ";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
$arr = explode( ',', $output);
$the_type = $arr[0];

if($the_type == 'samsung'){
echo 'samsung';
}

if($the_type == 'nokia'){
echo 'samsung';
}

if($the_type == 'iphone'){
echo 'samsung';
}
if($the_type == 'ipad'){
echo 'samsung';
}
else{
 echo 'exception';
 }
}
?>
```

The known brands are `samsung`,`nokia`,`iphone` etc.

However,there are many brands that are not well known and we want to ignore them.

My script looks like i have written above,only that i have left the actual code between my if's.

When i run the script,i get `exception` meaning none of the code inside ifs is getting executed. Is `if` the right method here?.

Note:

I have checked and counter-checked my `pl` script and its correct so it cannot be it.

Comment: Check the contents of each variable to ensure they contain what you expect.

Comment: `var_dump` your `$the_type` variable to see what it actually contains. The `==` comparison is case-sensitive and does not ignore whitespace or NUL bytes. Consider using a switch statement, or array map.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz and mario. Your suggestions made it work in the end.

Comment: Why don't you just use  `switch($the_type) {
case: 'samsung':
echo 'samsung';
break;
case: 'nokia':
echo 'nokia';
break;
case 'and-so-on':
echo 'and so on';
break;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `elseif` otherwise you will obtain "exception" everytime the terminal is not an ipad. All the conditions are mutually exclusive.

```
if ($the_type == 'samsung') {
    echo 'samsung';
} elseif ($the_type == 'nokia') {
    echo 'nokia';
} elseif ($the_type == 'iphone') {
    echo 'iphone';
} elseif ($the_type == 'ipad') {
    echo 'ipad';
} else {
   echo 'exception';
}
```

An other way to do it, is to use an array:

```
$models = ['samsung', 'nokia', 'iphone', 'ipad'];

if (in_array($the_type, $models))
    echo $the_type;
else
    echo 'exception';
```

If you don't get any result except "exception", check `$the_type` with `var_dump` to be sure it contains what you hope.